# Knockout component with conditional HTML markup in template:

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-components

I'm new with KO and KO components.

I currently have a `custom-component.js`, which perfectly works, to style all **inputs** of our project.
However, I'd like to get the exact same component working for **textareas**.

Currently, the `template:` part of this component looks like :

```
viewModel: function (params) {

    /*  */

    template: '<span data-bind="template: { afterRender: afterRender }">' +
        '<label class="custom-label" data-bind="css:{\'custom-label-active\':focused}, text:label"></label>' +
        '<input class="form-control" type="text" data-bind="enable: enable, valueUpdate: \'input\', css:{\'custom-label-input\':focused}, attr:{placeholder:label, id:id, type: type}, event:{focus:focus,blur:blur},value:value"/>' +
        '</span>'
});
```

How should I update it to make it work for textareas too ?

I tried to add a default parameter like this :

```
this.element = (params.element == undefined || params.element == null) ?  'input' : params.element
```

but I'm not sure how to update my markdown ?

Should I just replace `'<input'` by something like `'<' + self.element + '...>'`
What about the `valueUpdate` ? (I'm very new to all of this, sorry if it's a dumb question)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your template is shared by all of the component instances. There's no way to dynamically update it using the component's params, other than using knockouts own `if`, `template`, `with`, etc. bindings.

If you know it will only support a limited set of elements, you can add an `if` statement for each of them. E.g.:

```html
<!-- ko if: element === "input" -->
<input/>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: element === "textarea" -->
<textarea></textarea>
<!-- /ko -->
```

If you want to be able to pass *any* element, you could look in to using [`componentInfo.templateNodes`](https://knockoutjs.com/documentation/component-custom-elements.html#passing-markup-into-components)`. If that's what you want, let me know. I can extend my answer, but it's a more complicated approach.

Here's an example using the `if` binding:

```js
ko.components.register("custom-input", {
    viewModel: function(params) {
      return {
        elementType: params.elementType,
        value: ko.observable("Your input")
      }
    },
    template: `
    <div>
      <label>
        Your input here:<br>
        <!-- ko if: elementType() === 'input' -->
        <input type="text" data-bind="textInput: value">
        <!-- /ko -->
        
        <!-- ko if: elementType() === 'textarea' -->
        <textarea cols="40" rows="10" data-bind="textInput: value"></textarea>
        <!-- /ko -->
      </label>
    </div>
    `
});

ko.applyBindings({
  inputType: ko.observable("input")
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<h2>Config:</h2>
<label>
  <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: inputType" value="input">
  Use input
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" data-bind="checked: inputType" value="textarea">
  Use text area
</label>

<h2>Component:</h2>
<custom-input params="elementType: inputType"></custom-input>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that's what's I feard, I'll deal with it